# How to add constructor which accepts filed as a required parameter in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

So what I need In my User model I need to add a constructor to ensure the first name and last name are the required fields and rest as optional parameters.

```
class User(TimeStampedModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(320), nullable=False, unique=True)

    

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}, name: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}"
```

In here as you can see first name and last name present now when I add user I need to make sure that these 2 fields are required I want to use constructor for this.

How can I define constructors for different fields present in multiple models?

Comment: If you try to create a user without first name or last name doesn't it error? Since you already defined `nullable=False` all you have to do is error handling, either grab the form and check  for missing fields or send fields through and catch the error on insert.

Comment: That's what I've added but I want to add this required field using constructor. Is it possible to do so. sometimes user just add name and rest can be used as optional field.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.